# Could not find javafx-archetype-fxml in central Intellij JavaFX-Maven project

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, javafx

I'm following [this](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#maven) under the "JavaFX and Intellij" installing non-modular maven.

I input pretty much everything the same (I'm using version 15 of java, so 15.0.2)
I enter the exact same ids, I put "15.0.2" for javafx-version, and I have tried both "javafx-archetype-simple" and "javafx-archetype-fxml" and both give me the
error:

```
Could not find artifact org.javafx:javafx-archetype-fxml:pom:0.0.6 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)
```

And the following "pom.xml (<project_name>)":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>test1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>15</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>15</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

</project>
```

From the videos I've also seen on installing this, this is way too short. alongside the project structure itself being wrong. With the <project_name> directory only containing ".idea", "pom.xml" and "<project_name>.iml" files/folders.

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. I'm pretty sure I don't need to have JavaFX installed right (though I do somewhere)

Comment: IMO, the [OpenJFX Maven JavaFX archetypes](https://github.com/openjfx/javafx-maven-archetypes) are difficult to use with Idea and obsolete.  The [new project wizard as outlined in Basil's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71162687/1155209) is far superior and should be used instead of the archetypes.

Comment: "I'm pretty sure I don't need to have JavaFX installed right" -> yes, when creating a modular JavaFX project using maven as a build system, you do not need to install the JavaFX SDK, you can instead source just the JavaFX runtime components that you need directly from the maven repository through defined maven dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

## Use latest version of *IntelliJ*

As [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71162164/could-not-find-javafx-archetype-fxml-in-central-intellij-javafx-maven-project/71162687?noredirect=1#comment125796276_71162687), be sure you are using the latest version of [*IntelliJ*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA).

The IntelliJ [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) is a vast and rich tool, under continual development, with constantly improving features and fixes.

Tip: IntelliJ gives away the [*JetBrains Toolbox*](https://www.jetbrains.com/toolbox-app/) applet to automatically discover and install new versions, and optionally, pre-release versions.

## Use IntelliJ template

I recommend using the JavaFX project template built into [IntelliJ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA).

See [*Create a new JavaFX project*](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/javafx.html#check-plugin). Choose `File` > `New` > `Project` > `JavaFX`.

[image: screenshot of File New Project JavaFX dialog box]

This produces a [Maven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven)-driven project (or [Gradle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradle)-driven, your choice) using the [OpenJFX](https://openjfx.io/) libraries that implement [JavaFX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaFX). Upon creation, wait a minute while various libraries are downloaded and configured.

You said:

> I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. I'm pretty sure I don't need to have JavaFX installed right (though I do somewhere)

As [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71162164/could-not-find-javafx-archetype-fxml-in-central-intellij-javafx-maven-project/71162687?noredirect=1#comment125799657_71162164), there is indeed a separately downloadable collection of OpenJFX libraries. But I have never done that.

Instead, I recommend letting a dependency management tool (Maven or Gradle) handle fetching the OpenJFX libraries from a Maven repository. The dependency tool then makes those libraries available to your project for building and bundling with your final app. Switching to later versions is much easier through the dependency tool rather than having to manually download fresh copies, and manually install into your project.

An alternative is using an edition of a JDK that comes bundled with a copy of the OpenJFX libraries. At least two vendors provide such an edition of their JDK distributions: *ZuluFX* by Azul Systems, and *LibericaFX* by Bellsoft.

Comment: I do not get the option to do this. All I get to do is "File->New->Project->JavaFX->JavaFX Application->choose project name/location"
To clarify, I'm trying to do all of this so that my group and I can work on a project and not worry about JavaFX file paths.

Comment: @JamesGreen Are you saying you do not see the dialog shown in the screenshot within this Answer? Did you **verify the JavaFX plug-in is activated** in IntelliJ, as instructed in that documentation?

Comment: @JamesGreen I don’t understand the last sentence of your Comment. What do you mean by “JavaFX file paths”?

Comment: @JamesGreen Ensure that you are using the most recent IntelliJ Idea IDE version  (currently 2021.3 I believe).  [Download and install it](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/#section=windows) if necessary.  Either community of ultimate edition will work.

Comment: @BasilBourque I'm currently updating intellij so hopefully that will help. And I will look into "verifying the javaFX plug-in is activated". When I said "JavaFX file paths" I was referring to when I have the library manually downloaded in a file store, I was having difficulty finding  a way to have a relative file path for the JavaFX lib, and I found out maven was a good solution to this. Especially because I am working in a group.

Comment: @JamesGreen Yes, Maven takes care of downloading the OpenJFX libraries, and takes care of including them in your app when built. For a team, use a source control system such as Mercurial, Git, or Perforce to share a common code base. That code base includes your Maven POM file.